# How can I get a table of contents as below (triple page numbers)

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to typesetting a problem book with hints and solutions.

I want to get a TOC as

```
                TABLE OF CONTENTS

                            Problems   Hints    Solutions

    Chapter 1 Algebra          1         25        50
        problem 1.1            2         26        51
        problem 1.2            3         27        52
    .......................................................
    Chapter 2 Geometry        91        135       180
        problem 2.1           92        136       181
        problem 2.2           93        137       182
    .......................................................
```

How can I get the result? (I am more familiar with `titlesec` and `titletoc` package than others.)

BTW, I would input my source code like

```
\part{PROBLEMS}

\chapter{ALGEBRA}
\problem The first algebra question ...
\problem The second algebra question ...
...
\chapter{GEOMETRY}
\problem The first geometry question ...
\problem The second geometry question ...
...

\part{HINTS}

\chapter{ALGEBRA}
\hint The hint of the first algebra question ...
\hint The hint of the second algebra question ...
...
\chapter{GEOMETRY}
\hint The hint of the first geometry question ...
\hint The hint of the second geometry question ...
...

\part{SOLUTIONS}

\chapter{ALGEBRA}
\solution The solution of the first algebra question ...
\solution The solution of the second algebra question ...
...
\chapter{GEOMETRY}
\solution The solution of the first geometry question ...
\solution The solution of the second geometry question ...
...
```

or like

```
...

\chapter{ALGEBRA}
\problem The first algebra question ...
\hint The hint of the first algebra question ...
\solution The solution of the first algebra question ...

\problem The second algebra question ...
\hint The hint of the second algebra question ...
\solution The solution of the second algebra question ...
...
\chapter{GEOMETRY}
\problem The first geometry question ...
\hint The hint of the first geometry question ...
\solution The solution of the first geometry question ...

\problem The second geometry question ...
\hint The hint of the second geometry question ...
\solution The solution of the second geometry question ...
...
```

Which one is better? Welcome others suggestions.

Comment: Input as in the first code snippet is easier to handle from a coding point of view. The second code snippet is easier to handle from a structural point of view, since like elements are grouped together.

Comment: @user3122: I am writing a package at the moment which handles at least the grouping (as Werner called it) of problems and their solutions in one environment and postpones the output to the end of the file. However without hints and it is not ready for a release so far... The import key is to write the solution parts to a separate file and input that at the end. There are packages doing the already, perhaps also with some kind of a TOC you requested, e.g. `exam`?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer Thanks for information. I have tried the `exam` package, but it is not fitted for my requirement. Why don't you consider adding the hints environment into your package since provided solution parts? Are there some special difficults? It will take several rich months for me to provide the document. So I can wait your package. Thank you.

Comment: @Werner Taking account on the existing packages which could approximately achieve the purpose of the above listed TOC style, would you suggest for the first code or the second code? Thanks.

Comment: @user3122: My package works fine in my environment, it is quite configurable, but I will try to make a pre-release in few weeks, with hints added and some examples, but I can't guarantee neither for usability nor for the release time ;-) I my profile you can see the output of an older version...

Comment: I would go along a method based on `\label/\ref`. The labels would be generated according to values of some incremented suitable counters. The `.aux` files would be used then to store at the end of the document the final values of the counters. Based on this the table could be generated by a suitable loop. `\xintFor` could help there for that final step (iterating inside a longtable environment). I would drop trying the table of contents mechanism for that, although it could be done too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I provide a proposition of a solution, making the Problem - Hint - Solution (PHS) approach, using some coding techniques from my package (still under construction)

I had to redefine `\part` and `\chapter` commands, but omitted `\section` etc.

> The basic command is `\PHS` which takes at most four parameters:
>
> 1st . parameter is optional, currently only `NoHint=true/false` or
>   `NoSolution=true/false` are supported. Use them to hide the hint
>   and/or the solution.
>
> 2nd parameter: Problem/question content 3rd parameter: Hint content
>   4th parameter: Solution content.
>
> The hint and solution contents are written to external files and
>   readin afterwards.
>
> `\MyTableOfContents` shows a (crude) setup of the triple toc as
>   requested.

The colour boxes are just eye - candy.

**Note**
The content of an individual box might shift to another page whereas the automatic label anchor is currently outside of the box. The setting of the labels should be done inside not outside, but this is left to the final use of the question/hint/solution look.

There are definitely some errors in this code which I do not have in mind now ;-)

**Update** According to jfbu there were some unnecessary `\expandafter` statements. I removed them.

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{scrbook}
\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{bbding}%
\usepackage{dingbat}%
\usepackage{xkeyval}%

\usepackage[final,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=4,pageanchor,pdftoolbar=true]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{bookmark}%


\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=0 0 1}%

\newcounter{phs}[chapter]%

\newwrite\hintsfile%
\newwrite\solutionfile%
\newwrite\phstocfile%

\newrobustcmd{\NoHintTocSymbol}{\Peace}%
\newrobustcmd{\NoSolutionTocSymbol}{\Peace}%

\newrobustcmd{\ProblemName}{Problem}%
\newrobustcmd{\HintName}{Hint}%
\newrobustcmd{\SolutionName}{Solution}%


\newrobustcmd{\PHSKeyFamily}{PHSKeys}%

\newrobustcmd{\ProvideBool}[2][false]{%
\providebool{#2}%
\setbool{#2}{#1}
\long\csgdef{Enable#2}{%
\booltrue{#2}%
}%
\long\csgdef{Disable#2}{%
\boolfalse{#2}%
}%
}%


\makeatletter

\ProvideBool{NoHint}%
\define@boolkey{\PHSKeyFamily}{NoHint}[false]{%
\ifKV@PHSKeys@NoHint%
\EnableNoHint%
\else%
\DisableNoHint%
\fi%
}%

\ProvideBool{NoSolution}%
\define@boolkey{\PHSKeyFamily}{NoSolution}[false]{%
\ifKV@PHSKeys@NoSolution%
\EnableNoSolution%
\else%
\DisableNoSolution%
\fi%
}%


\makeatother


\AtBeginDocument{%
\immediate\openout\phstocfile=\jobname.phstoc%
\immediate\openout\hintsfile=\jobname.hin%
\immediate\openout\solutionfile=\jobname.sol%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
\immediate\closeout\phstocfile%
\immediate\closeout\hintsfile%
\immediate\closeout\solutionfile%
}%

\renewcommand{\thephs}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{phs}}%

\newrobustcmd{\problemnumberref}[3][]{%
\expandafter{\textbf{\ProblemName\ #2.#3}}%
}

\newrobustcmd{\problempageref}[3][]{%
\pageref{\unexpanded{phs::#2::#3}}%
}%


\newrobustcmd{\hintpageref}[3][]{%
\setkeys{\PHSKeyFamily}{#1}%
\ifboolexpr{bool{NoHint}}{\textcolor{blue}{\NoHintTocSymbol}}{%
\pageref{\unexpanded{hint::#2::#3}}
}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\solutionpageref}[3][]{%
\setkeys{\PHSKeyFamily}{#1}%
\ifboolexpr{bool{NoSolution}}{\textcolor{blue}{\NoHintTocSymbol}}{%
\pageref{\unexpanded{solution::#2::#3}}%
}%
}%



\newrobustcmd{\WritePHSTocInfo}[3][]{%
\setkeys{\PHSKeyFamily}{#1}%
\immediate\write\phstocfile{%
\string\hspace{1em}\problemnumberref{#2}{#3} & \problempageref[#1]{#2}{#3} & \hintpageref[#1]{#2}{#3} & \solutionpageref[#1]{#2}{#3}%
\tabularnewline%
}%
}%




\newrobustcmd{\PHS}[4][]{%
\setkeys{\PHSKeyFamily}{#1}%
\refstepcounter{phs}%
\phantomsection%
\label{phs::\number\value{chapter}::\number\value{phs}}%
\WritePHSTocInfo[#1]{\number\value{chapter}}{\number\value{phs}}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,coltitle=black,colbacktitle=yellow,title=\textbf{\ProblemName\ \thephs}]
#2
\end{tcolorbox}
\immediate\write\hintsfile{%
\string\PHSHint[#1]{\unexpanded\expandafter{#3}}% 
}%
\immediate\write\solutionfile{%
\string\PHSSolution[#1]{\unexpanded\expandafter{#4}}% 
}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\PHSHint}[2][]{%
\setkeys{\PHSKeyFamily}{#1}%
%\refstepcounter{phshint}%
\refstepcounter{phs}%
\phantomsection%
\label{hint::\number\value{chapter}::\number\value{phs}}%
\ifboolexpr{bool{NoHint}}{}{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,colbacktitle=red,coltitle=black,title=\textbf{{\HintName\ \thephs}}]%
#2%  
\end{tcolorbox}%
}%
\DisableNoHint%  
}%


\newrobustcmd{\PHSSolution}[2][]{%
\setkeys{\PHSKeyFamily}{#1}%
%\refstepcounter{phssolution}%
\refstepcounter{phs}%
\phantomsection%
\label{solution::\number\value{chapter}::\number\value{phs}}%
\ifboolexpr{bool{NoSolution}}{}{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,colbacktitle=cyan,coltitle=black,title=\textbf{{\SolutionName\ \thephs}}]%
#2%
\end{tcolorbox}%
}%
\DisableNoSolution%
}%


\newcommand*{\ListOfProblemsName}{List of Problems}%

\newrobustcmd{\MyTableOfContents}{%
\cleardoublepage%
\phantomsection%
%\pdfbookmark[0]{\ListOfProblemsName}{bookmark::mytableofcontents}%

\pagestyle{plain}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect{\ListOfProblemsName}}
\begin{longtable}{lrrr}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\large{\textbf{Problems}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\large{\textbf{Hints}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\large{\textbf{Solutions}}}   \tabularnewline
\WritePreChapterEmptyLine%
\endhead%
\IfFileExists{\jobname.phstoc}{%
\input{\jobname.phstoc}%
}{}%
\end{longtable}
}%


\makeatletter
\newcounter{InternalChapterCounter}

\newrobustcmd{\hintsfilechapterstartup}[2]{%
  \phantomsection%
  \pdfbookmark{#1}{hint::chapter::\number\value{#2}}%
  \begingroup
  \setcounter{InternalChapterCounter}{\number\value{#2}}%
  \addtocounter{InternalChapterCounter}{-1}
  \bookmarksetup{depth=-1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect{\arabic{InternalChapterCounter}.\ #1}}%
  \endgroup
  \LaTeXStandardChapter[]{#1}%

}%


\newrobustcmd{\postponedfilechapterstartup}[3]{%
  \cleardoublepage%
  \phantomsection%
  \begingroup%
  \setcounter{InternalChapterCounter}{\number\value{#2}}%
  \addtocounter{InternalChapterCounter}{1}%
  \bookmarksetup{depth=-1}%  Prevent bookmarking by \addcontentsline
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect{\number\value{InternalChapterCounter}.\ #1}}%
  \endgroup%
  \LaTeXStandardChapter[]{#1}%
  \phantomsection
  \pdfbookmark{#1}{#3::chapter::\number\value{chapter}}%
}%


\newrobustcmd{\WritePreChapterEmptyLine}{%
\ifnumgreater{\number\value{chapter}}{0}{%
\immediate\write\phstocfile{%
\string & & & \tabularnewline%
}}{%
% Do nothing
}%
}%

\newcounter{dummychaptercounter}%
\let\LaTeXStandardChapter\chapter%

\newrobustcmd{\@phschapter@noopt}[1]{%
\LaTeXStandardChapter{#1}%
\immediate\write\hintsfile{%
  \string\postponedfilechapterstartup{#1}{chapter}{hint}%
}%
\immediate\write\solutionfile{%
  \string\postponedfilechapterstartup{#1}{chapter}{solution}%
}%
\WritePreChapterEmptyLine%
\immediate\write\phstocfile{%
\string\expandafter\unexpanded{{\Large\textbf{\chaptername{} #1}}} & & & \tabularnewline%
\string  & & & \tabularnewline
}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\@phschapter@opt}[2][]{%
%%%% Do not use this, it is not correct so far!!!
\setcounter{dummychaptercounter}{\number\value{chapter}}%
\addtocounter{dummychaptercounter}{1}%
\renewcommand{\thedummychaptercounter}{\arabic{dummychaptercounter}.}%
\immediate\write\hintsfile{%
  \string\phantomsection%
  \string\pdfbookmark{#2}{hint::chapter::\number\value{chapter}}%
  \string\LaTeXStandardChapter[]{#2}%
}%
\immediate\write\solutionfile{%
 \string\phantomsection%
 \string\pdfbookmark{#2}{solution::chapter::\number\value{chapter}}%
 \string\LaTeXStandardChapter[]{#2}%
}%
\immediate\write\phstocfile{%
\string\expandafter\unexpanded{{\Large\textbf{\chaptername{} #2}}} & & & \tabularnewline%
}%
\LaTeXStandardChapter[#1]{#2}% This is the problem chapter
}%




\newrobustcmd{\phschapter}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\@phschapter@opt}{\@phschapter@noopt}
}%

\newrobustcmd{\phsstarredchapter}[1]{%
\LaTeXStandardChapter*{#1}%
}%

\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
\@ifstar{\phsstarredchapter}{\phschapter}%
}%


\let\LaTeXStandardPart\part%

\renewcommand{\part}[1]{%
\immediate\write\hintsfile{%
  \string\setcounter{chapter}{0}%
}%
\immediate\write\solutionfile{%
  \string\setcounter{chapter}{0}%
}%
\LaTeXStandardPart{#1}%
}%


\makeatother


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}%

\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage%
\phantomsection%
\tableofcontents % Normal table of contents

\MyTableOfContents % List of problems etc. 


\part{Problems}

\chapter{Algebra}
\PHS[NoHint=true]{Show that \(\left({a+b}\right)^2 = a^2 + 2\cdot a \cdot b +b^2\)}{Multiply!!!}{Solution to be done}
\PHS[NoHint=false]{Show that \(\left({a-b}\right)^2 = a^2 - 2\cdot a \cdot b +b^2\)}{Multiply!!!}{Solution to be done}
\PHS{Show that \[\left({a-b}\right)\cdot\left({a+b}\right)  = a^2 - b^2 \]} {Multiply!!!}{Solution to be done}
\PHS[NoHint=true]{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%
\PHS{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}{Dummy Algebra}%


\chapter{Geometry}

\PHS{Show that \(c^2 =  a^2 + b^2\)}{Tricky partitioning of a square}{Solution to be done}
\PHS[NoSolution=true]{Show that \Huge\[\sin^2\left({\alpha}\right) + \cos^2\left({\alpha}\right) \equiv 1 \]\normalsize}{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}%
\PHS{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}%
\PHS{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}%
\PHS{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}%
\PHS{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}%
\PHS{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}%
\PHS{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}%
\PHS{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}%
\PHS{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}%
\PHS{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}%
\PHS{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}{Dummy Geometry}%

\chapter{Calculus}
\PHS{Dummy Calculus}{Dummy Calculus}{Dummy Calculus}%
\PHS{Dummy Calculus}{Dummy Calculus}{Dummy Calculus}%

\chapter{Matrix calculations}

\PHS{Dummy Matrix}{Dummy Matrix}{Dummy Matrix}%
\PHS{Dummy Matrix}{Dummy Matrix}{Dummy Matrix}%


\clearpage

\part{Hints}

\IfFileExists{\jobname.hin}{\input{\jobname.hin}}{}

\part{Solutions}

\IfFileExists{\jobname.sol}{\input{\jobname.sol}}{}


\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: things such as `\expandafter\pageref{` in the code look strange. Perhaps you meant `\expandafter\pageref\expandafter{` ? (although this would still be strange because the next token is `\unexpanded`). In a similar vain `\unexpanded\expandafter{solution` looks very strange. Do you mean the `s` of solution should be expanded before the `{`? But both are unexpandable.

Comment: @jfbu: You are right, that commands are remainders of old code I introduced intermediately to keep LaTeX quiet, but after reading your comment I realised that they those `\expandafter` commands are not needed there.

Comment: @christian Hupfer Thanks your help. I will try your code.

Comment: @user3122: You made a comment about a bonus question, but I could not read it, something about 'omitting' hint? Perhaps you deleted it?